# Any way to send Push with Parse on Node.js with client push disabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using a Node.js server in conjunction with Parse for my mobile app.  All of my push messages are sent from Node.  However, as I read the documentation, I MUST have 'client push' enabled because there is no `useMasterKey` option for `Parse.Push.send({})`.

Is this correct?

I am trying to avoid the [security implications](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/) that come with having client push enabled, but as best as I can see, my only options is to use the REST API instead of the Javascript SDK to send the pushes because the REST API allows you to set the Master Key header on any request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. From your node.js server

1. call REST API to send push notifications
2. call Parse Cloud Code function to send push notifications. Parse Cloud Code also doesn't need `client push` as enabled. Also you can use `useMasterKey`.